# Can't understand where to store custom types in typescript project

Tags: javascript, typescript

Typescript is awesome, types are awesome, but it's not so easy for some scenarios.

I'm fighting with typescript for a few days, i can't understand where to place my types that need to be used across whole project.

I know that that types can be included in `*.ts` file, and they will be erased when compiled. But, if i need that `type` in another module than i need to import it with relative path. But it seems ugly.. if i move that file to another location than i will break half of project.

So i went with idea that types should be independent of the place where it's used.

I've read about declaration merging, and it looks like that is what i want.

My objectives:

I want to build a library (for nodejs) that will be used in another typescript project and (maybe) pure javascript project.

Obviously, the output of my library will be `*.js` and `*.d.ts` files. I don't want publish `*.ts` files because i want compile them once and it may be used in pure js project (i don't want bring typescript compiler there)

One file (module), contains single function. 
That function has `input` and `output`. Types for `input` and `output` is written in `d.ts` file

```
declare namespace library.foo {

type main = () => out

type out = {
   name: string
}

}
```

and next to declaration i place file with implementation (foo.ts):

```
createFoo: library.foo.main = () {
return { name: "baz"}
}
```

After running `tsc i` i see this output for `foo.d.ts` in dist folder:

```
declare const createFoo: library.foo.main
```

my hand written declaration file has left in source folder, and it's not in dist folder.

Is there any option in tsc that will emit single declaration file with all my types? That file will be published with generated `.js` files and all `.t.ds` files

Comment: I don't see why types or TypeScript make any distinction for this question. Don't you have functions that need to be used across the whole project? How are you dealing with that? The same solution will work for types.

Comment: @artem For me types are domain logic. They can be used in any function, produced by any function. Types are going from one function to another. So types should be independent of concrete function. If i move or delete one function implementation it should not break project